# GitHub/Git comVS Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

Boa tarde, Senhores,
Estou trabalhando com o VisualStudio Code,eu preciso enviar alguns arquivos para o github, porem sempre que inicio o commit me aparece uma mensagem de erro, não permitindo continuar, (segue abaixo), existe alguma configuração que tenha que fazer? Podeira me passar algum modo de corrigir isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parece que ele fala que os arquivos já existem, e ele manda vc dar o comando `git add -A -- .` eu não sei exatamente o que isso vai acarretar, então se vc der o comando é por sua conta...

Comment: Nossa, existe alguma forma de corrigir isso?